# if $\sum n! $ converges in $\mathbb{Z_p}$ ring then what about convergence of $\sum n$?

Tags: ring-theory, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

I have read in some notebook about P-adic numbers , I accrossed that $\sum n! $ converges in $\mathbb{Z_p}$ but not's clear what value can take , Now my question here is :
if $\sum n! $  converges in $\mathbb{Z_p}$ does $\sum n$  also converges in the same ring using comparaison creterion ?

Comment: $n!=0$ for $n>p$, so that's why it converges. The other one doesn't have that property.

Comment: Helpful fact: An infinite series $\sum_{n≥0} a_n $over the $p$-adic numbers (or any field with a non-trivial nonarchimedean absolute value) converges if and only if $|a_n|_p \to 0$. Try showing this!

Comment: @StanTendijck Here $\Bbb{Z}_p$ stands for the ring of $p$-adic integers. That ring contains $\Bbb{Z}$ as a subring.  Consequently $n!\neq0$ here.

Comment: What Parthiv Basu says. The sum $\sum_n n$ fails the simplest convergence test for $\lim_{n\to\infty}|1+np|=1\neq0$. Therefore something went wrong. Arthur's answer does explain a way of looking at it.

Comment: And also $|k|_p\le1$ for all integers $k$, so $|n!|_p\le |n|_p$, and there cannot be any talk of a comparison test for the inequality goes in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what convergence usually means in $\Bbb Z_p$: That more and more digits (counting from the right) stop changing as the sequence goes on. In base $p$ (for any prime $p$), the elements of the sequence $n!$ gets more and more trailing zeroes, meaning any specific digit of $\sum n!$ is eventually fixed and doesn't change any more, which again means that the sum converges. This doesn't happen with $\sum n$.

Be careful with the comparison test: the standard "ordering" of $p$-adic integers isn't directly related to the standard ordering of the integers: $1000$ is less than $100$, and $n!$ is usually *much* smaller than $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting Stan Tendijck's comment to Jyrki Lahtonen's correct critique:

$\lvert n!\rvert_p \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$, so that's why it converges. The other one does not have that property (i.e. $\lvert n \rvert_p \not \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$.)